# Differentiate between calls to the same delegate method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, delegates

Let's imagine I have a method: `-[myClass getDataForUser:user]` and when it is done it calls a delegate's method `gotData:` and the results appear on my main class. If I do two calls to `getDataForUser:`, for example:

```
[myClass getDataForUser:@"user1"];
[myClass getDataForUser:@"user2"];
```

how can I differentiate between these two calls in the delegate method?

## EDIT:

The library is MGTwitterEngine, the two calls I make are `-[_engine getDirectMessagesSinceID:1 startingAtPage:1];` and `[_engine getSentDirectMessagesSinceID:1 startingAtPage:1];` and the delegate method is `directMessagesReceived:forRequest:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an instance of MGTwitterEngine for each call, and give each instance a different delegate object. Inside each of these delegate objects, you can store the user id. Set these delegate objects so they can accept your original class as *their* delegates. Then you can use delegate gotData:(id)data forUser:(NSString *)user finally. Not pretty, but may work.

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument to the delegate's method:

```
[delegate gotData:(id)data forUser:(NSString *)user]
```

There are other ways, but not nearly as clean and easy

Edit: OK, it's in a library so it can't be changed.  However, the delegate does have a `for[something]` argument, in this case `forRequest`.  So, all you need to do is find a way to associate a request with a username.  I suggest putting them in a map, mapping `request` to `user`.  Or, if you only have the two, you could just make a couple variables `request1, request2` and `user1, user2` and store the request and user in the appropriate variables, checking for which id goes with which name (in the delegate):

```
if(thisRequest == request1) {
    thisUser = user1; 
} else {
    thisUser = user2;
}
```

Comment: yeah but keeping in mind that class' delegate is a class I can't edit (the class or library is MGTwitterEngine, and the methods are `[_engine getDirectMessagesSinceID:1 startingAtPage:1];` and `[_engine getSentDirectMessagesSinceID:1 startingAtPage:1];`)

Comment: Is the delegate method guaranteed to be called before the `getData` call returns, or is it asynchronous?

Comment: getData's data gets on the delegate method